# How to have identity provider configuration page visible in Keycloak?

Tags: plugins, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm writing a custom identity provider for Keycloa that I want to deploy using the [deployer](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.5/server_development/index.html#using-the-keycloak-deployer) method (since I want to deploy it in [Docker containers](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/)). Following an [example](https://github.com/Reventl0v/KeycloakCAS) I found on the web, I've created a maven project where, using the maven-assembly-plugin, I build a jar with dependencies (but I've filtered out the various services implementations my dependencies provide me to just keep the identity provider service).

Things seems to work partly correctly :

- Keycloak log indicates my id provider is loading/loaded : `keycloak_1        | 09:23:20,056 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "mycompnay-oidc-id-provider-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" (runtime-name :
  "mycompany-oidc-id-provider-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar")`
- When I go in the *Identity Providers* panel, the new provider is visible (see screenshot)

[image: my id provider is loaded !]

But when I try to configure it, everything fails :

[image: I should have a configuration screen]

The problem is that Keycloak outputs strictly no logs (even when I configure log level to the max).

In my project, I have he following code organization (which gets replicated in jar-with-dependencies)

```
+---src
    +---build
    |   \---assembly
    +---main
    |   +---java
    |   |   \---com
    |   |       \---mycompany
    |   |           \---mygroup
    |   |               \---security
    |   |                   \---oidc
    |   \---resources
    |       +---META-INF
    |       |   \---services
    |       \---themes
    |           \---base
    |               \---admin
    |                   \---resources
    |                       \---partials
    \---test
        +---java
        \---resources
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you've figured this out by now.

It's not very well documented... I've done something similar a month ago and I faced the same problem. I've figured it out pretty much by poking and guessing, so it might not be the best way to do it but I'll say what I know on this:

You need both the idp and the partial page registered properly.
To be honest I have no idea if you can just extend the base keycloak admin theme in that way. I've tried it but failed horribly. So I've created my own theme extending the base one:

*assuming your idp is called* `foo`

---

`src/main/resources/theme/foo/admin/theme.properties`

```
parent=keycloak
import=common/keycloak
```

---

`src/main/resources/theme/foo/admin/resources/partials/realm-identity-provider-foo.html`

```
<div data-ng-include 
  data-src="resourceUrl + '/partials/realm-identity-provider-oidc.html'">
</div>
```

---

`src/main/resources/theme/foo/admin/resources/partials/realm-identity-provider-foo.html`

```
<div data-ng-include 
  data-src="resourceUrl + '/partials/realm-identity-provider-oidc.html'">
</div>
```

(I'm using oidc as my idp is extending that one, but you can use whatever makes sense for your case here)

---

`src/main/resources/theme/foo/admin/resources/partials/realm-identity-provider-foo-ext.html`
*this last file is empty in my case, but as far as I remember you must have it*

---

Then, on the admin console, you need to go and change your admin theme to be `foo`, and you must refresh your browser so it starts picking up the resources from your new theme. It's important to note that if you are logged in with a user from another realm (e.g. admin from master realm), you have to change the admin theme in master realm, since this is the theme you are actually using now.
If successful you should start seeing in your devtools that template resources now come from your theme, e.g. `auth/resources/4.4.0.final/admin/foo/templates/kc-tabs-realm.html`
If that's the case then your idp page should be working, or at least you should be able to pick it up from here.

I know it's not the perfect answer, but it might give you a hint on things to consider.

If you make progress or find a better way please share!

Comment: In fact, it's also possible to extend standard theme by just dropping the missing files. Anyway thanks for answering !

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the amount of time you've probably just saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Resolved by renaming jar file to:

```
keycloak-{identity provider name}-{version}-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Before that the file was called:

```
keycloak-{identity provider name}-idp-plugin-{version}-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

…and I was getting "resource not found" error. I suppose keycloak is looking for resources in archives with a name that matches a certain pattern.