# Keycloak display custom creation page for custom IDP

Tags: keycloak

I try to create a custom IDP for keycloak.

So for test purposes I've written a **Provider** and a **ProviderFactory** class both inheriting from their respective SAML counterpart (really only changing the display name and provider ID so far).

```
public class MySAMLIdentityProviderFactory extends SAMLIdentityProviderFactory {

  public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "my-saml";

  private DestinationValidator destinationValidator;

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "my SAML";
  }

  @Override
  public MySAMLIdentityProvider create(KeycloakSession session, IdentityProviderModel model) {
    return new MySAMLIdentityProvider(session, new SAMLIdentityProviderConfig(model), destinationValidator);
  }

  @Override
  public String getId() {
    return PROVIDER_ID;
  }

  @Override
  public void init(Scope config) {
    super.init(config);

    this.destinationValidator = DestinationValidator.forProtocolMap(config.getArray("knownProtocols"));
  }
}

public class MySAMLIdentityProvider extends SAMLIdentityProvider {

  public MySAMLIdentityProvider(KeycloakSession session, SAMLIdentityProviderConfig config, DestinationValidator destinationValidator) {
    super(session, config, destinationValidator);
  }
}
```

Following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52757115/how-to-have-identity-provider-configuration-page-visible-in-keycloak) I also added a **realm-identity-provider-my-saml.html** and a **realm-identity-provider-my-saml-ext.html** under ./themes/base/admin/resources/partials.
The **-ext** being empty and the other html looking like this:

```
<div data-ng-include data-src="resourceUrl + '/partials/realm-identity-provider-saml.html'"></div>
```

I can now go to the admin browser console and add this new IDP to my realm.
Uppon creation however, I am not asked for SAML attributes like "Use entity descriptor" or "Display name".
Instead I get the creation screen for social providers asking for "Client-ID" and "Client-Secret".

[image: wrong creation screen]

Only after initial creation, the common SAML attributes appear and can be configured.

[image: configuration screen]

How can I get Keycloak to display the propper SAML IDP creation screen?

Edit:
I use Keycloak version 19.0.1.
The issue seems to be connected to the new Keycloak.v2 theme which is weird since as far as I can see the v2 theme does not overwrite the admin resources only the account resources.

Answer (score 0):

So, keycloak has an [open issue](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/15344) for this.......